# Load checkbox it from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my activity and managed to saved it to the sqlite database. I saved my checkbox to a string "True" to show it checked and "False" for unchecked.  But now I'm stuck on how to call back the checkbox value and load it so all the checkbox get checked based on the value that I had in the database.

How should I do it? Thanks

Here is my code.

**PreDiveBK.java**

```
public class PreDiveBK extends Activity {

private DBOperations db;
String pd1 =  "False";
CheckBox cb1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.predbk);

    db = new DBOperations(this);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                pd1 = "True";
            }else{
                pd1 = "False";
            }
        }
    });
}

public void Save(View view)
{
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("add_info_predivebk", pd1);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: you have to get the row related to that checkbox from database, and then get that field value, parse it to boolean `Boolean.parseBoolean()` and set it in checkbox `chk.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(valFromDb))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the value from db and check

```
if (pd.equals("True"))
{ 
cb1.setChecked(true);
}else 
cb1.setChecked(false)
```

Comment: Kindly Search "retrieve value from sqlite db"